# No email received when sent with contact form

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

When I am filling out the contact form on the website that I am making, the e-mail will be sent, but I am not receiving it in the inbox of my computer. 
The code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <form action="mailto:psteintj@xs4all.nl" id="contactForm" method="post">
        <span></span>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Enter your name" tabindex=1 />
        <span></span>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter your email" tabindex=2 />
        <span id="captcha"></span>
        <input type="text" name="captcha" class="captcha" maxlength="4" size="4" placeholder="Enter captcha code" tabindex=3 />
        <span></span>
        <textarea class="message" placeholder="Enter your message" tabindex=4></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send e-mail" class="submit" tabindex=5>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if ((captchaVal == captchaCode) && (emailFilter.test(emailText)) && (nameFilter.test(nameText)) && (messageText > 50)) {
  $.post("mail.php", {
  name: $(".name").val(),
  email: $(".email").val(),
  message:$(".message").val()
  }); 
  $("#contactForm").css("display", "none");
  $("#form").append("<h2>Message sent!</h2>");
  return false;
}
```

and PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $POST['message'];
```

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing there must be more PHP than you posted? And do you have an active mail server?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not sending any emails (or at least you haven't posted any code about it), so of course you are not receiving any emails. You should configure the mailing, and use the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

The function needs a working SMTP server to actually send out the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP has no mail() call or similar? I'm probably missing something here.